# How do I use the "correct" error term in PROC MIXED to conduct specific contrasts?

Tags: mixed-model, sas, contrasts, nested-data

I have a SAS PROC MIXED question and I hope that y'all would be able to help me. It is my first time posting a question on here.

First, an analog to help define the question: Imagine that a researcher has a predictor with three levels and one outcome measure. The researcher is interested in testing the main effect and the various orthogonal contrasts. To conduct such an analysis, the researcher would simply conduct an one-way ANOVA and then the planned orthogonal contrasts. The error term for the orthogonal contrasts would (or should) be estimated from the error term for the ANOVA (i.e., from the mean square error). The overall error term would be used because it reflects the most informed estimate of the variability in the sample.

Here's the question. Using PROC MIXED, let us say that I am interested in assessing the impact of year in school (12 levels; 1st grade to 12th grade), nested by school district, on aggressive behavior. Suppose that I have a legitimate, theoretically grounded reason to test sex differences for only one grade (e.g., sex differences in aggressive behavior among 11th graders, with the subsample still nested by school district). The question is, how can I test this specific test using the analogous "overall error term" in PROC MIXED? All options I have seen require splitting the file into 12 parts to test the analysis separately for school year (split by year in school). However, assuming homogeneity and a clear theoretical prediction, how could the "overall error term" be specified in PROC MIXED to test the specific hypothesis?

To put the question simply, is it possible to apply the logic of testing simple orthogonal contrasts to the more complicated nested structure of PROC MIXED? What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Please remove the code formatting, it makes your question hard to read. Also, questions focusing on *programming, debugging, or performing routine operations within a statistical computing platform* are [off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. You may want to edit your question to clarify and emphasize (more) the underlying statistical issue.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.